# Erro ao adicionar PageViewAdapter no Google Maps API Android

Tags: android, google-maps, android-fragment, android-adapter

Possui três (3) botões e uma (1) tab com dois(2) botões no mapa, assim
que eu adiciono o código para criar as PageAdapters eu recebo erro e
não sei como solucionar.

**ERRO:**

> 03-15 03:50:23.990
>   3051-3051/com.thiagosaadcorporation.atendimentosecretaria
>   E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                                                                                                  Process: com.thiagosaadcorporation.atendimentosecretaria, PID: 3051
>                                                                                                  java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity
>   ComponentInfo{com.thiagosaadcorporation.atendimentosecretaria/com.thiagosaadcorporation.atendimentosecretaria.API.google.googleMaps.GoogleMapsActivity}:
>   java.lang.NullPointerException
>                                                                                                      at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2195)
>                                                                                                      at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
>                                                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
>                                                                                                      at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
>                                                                                                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>                                                                                                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
>                                                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
>                                                                                                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>                                                                                                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
>                                                                                                      at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
>                                                                                                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
>                                                                                                      at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
>                                                                                                   Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
>                                                                                                      at
>   com.thiagosaadcorporation.atendimentosecretaria.API.google.googleMaps.GoogleMapsActivity.setupViewPager(GoogleMapsActivity.java:75)
>                                                                                                      at
>   com.thiagosaadcorporation.atendimentosecretaria.API.google.googleMaps.GoogleMapsActivity.onCreate(GoogleMapsActivity.java:45)
>                                                                                                      at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
>                                                                                                      at
>   android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
>                                                                                                      at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2159)
>                                                                                                      at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245) 
>                                                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135) 
>                                                                                                      at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196) 
>                                                                                                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
>                                                                                                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136) 
>                                                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017) 
>                                                                                                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
>                                                                                                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
>                                                                                                      at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779) 
>                                                                                                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595) 
>                                                                                                      at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

**GoogleMapsAcitivity.java**

```
package com.thiagosaadcorporation.atendimentosecretaria.API.google.googleMaps;

import android.support.design.widget.TabLayout;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Button;

import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;
import com.thiagosaadcorporation.atendimentosecretaria.API.fragments.SectionsPageAdapter;
import com.thiagosaadcorporation.atendimentosecretaria.API.fragments.tabs.MapInformationsFragment;
import com.thiagosaadcorporation.atendimentosecretaria.API.fragments.tabs.UserAccountFragment;
import com.thiagosaadcorporation.atendimentosecretaria.R;

public class GoogleMapsActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {

    private GoogleMap mMap;
    private static final String TAG = "GoogleMapsActivity";

    private SectionsPageAdapter mSectionsPageAdapter;
    private ViewPager mViewPager;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_google_maps);
        Log.d(TAG, "onCreate: STARTING..");

        // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
        SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);

        mSectionsPageAdapter = new SectionsPageAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

        // Set up the ViewPager with the sections adapter.
        mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.container);
        setupViewPager(mViewPager);

        TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
        tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(mViewPager);
    }


    /**
     * Manipulates the map once available.
     * This callback is triggered when the map is ready to be used.
     * This is where we can add markers or lines, add listeners or move the camera. In this case,
     * we just add a marker near Sydney, Australia.
     * If Google Play services is not installed on the device, the user will be prompted to install
     * it inside the SupportMapFragment. This method will only be triggered once the user has
     * installed Google Play services and returned to the app.
     */
    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        mMap = googleMap;

        // Add a marker in Sydney and move the camera
        LatLng sydney = new LatLng(-34, 151);
        mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(sydney).title("Marker in Sydney"));
        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(sydney));
    }

    private void setupViewPager(ViewPager viewPager) {
        SectionsPageAdapter adapter = new SectionsPageAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
        adapter.addFragment(new UserAccountFragment(), "TAB1");
        adapter.addFragment(new MapInformationsFragment(), "TAB2");
        viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
}
```

**SectionsPageAdapter.java**

```
package com.thiagosaadcorporation.atendimentosecretaria.API.fragments;

import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

/**
 * Created by saadt on 15/03/2018.
 */

public class SectionsPageAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    private final List<Fragment> mFragmentList = new ArrayList<>();
    private final List<String> mFragmentTitleList = new ArrayList<>();

    public void addFragment(Fragment fragment, String title) {
        mFragmentList.add(fragment);
        mFragmentTitleList.add(title);
    }

    public SectionsPageAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        return mFragmentTitleList.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        return mFragmentList.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mFragmentList.size();
    }
}
```

Comment: O erro esta na linha 75 da GoogleMapsAcitivity. Nullpointer provavelmente causado pelo viewpager estar null.

Comment: @MaxFratane sim, o erro eu sei onde está. Mas eu fiz de acordo com a documentação e não sei o que devo fazer.

Comment: Ja colocou uns break points ai e debugou? O viewpager ta vindo null, ou seja, o findviewbyid nao encontrou nada com o id que vc passou. Verifica no xml se o id do viewpager ta container.

Comment: @MaxFratane consegui, era a id que estava errada.